# How do I add Post Like and Bookmark Functionality to my WordPress Site?

Tags: customization

on a wordpress site, I'd like visitors to be able to "like" or "save"  posts, so that they have a personalized page with all the posts they liked.
how could that be achieved?

thanks

Comment: I made your question more broad, as it is totally independent from what you publish in your posts. So hopefully this will get some answers.

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a really nice plugin for this, named WP Favorite Posts

> http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-favorite-posts/

It saves the data in the database if the user is logged in, and if they are just visiting, the data is stored in a cookie.