# Is there a way to save different data when USER interacts with the same POST?

Tags: posts, categories, custom-field, database, users

I would like a kind of relationship database without create database because I’m not very confident with it.

So I think about an alternative using Wordpress default features like posts, categories and users.

(I intend to use REST API, to do those actions, it’s okay about that. The problematic is about the save data by user)

So, The idea is USER adds POST to « My Likes CATEGORY.

Each user has his own category even the category is identical (even same ID maybe)

For example ADMINISTRATOR creates a category MY LIKES, but the content of the category is different for each user

Example:

1 - USER1 likes the POST-38, so the post would be added to category named MY LIKES

2 - USER2 likes the POST-38, POST-39 and POST-40 so these post would be added to same category named MY LIKES but which as not the same content a USER1

So In Wordpress admin could see My Likes category and inside ALL interaction :
- user1 / post-38
- user2 / post-38
- user2 / post-39
- user2 / post-40

Is there a way to do something like this?

Comment: Are your posts also created by wordpress? or they are in another system?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add Post Like and Bookmark Functionality to my WordPress Site?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2148/how-do-i-add-post-like-and-bookmark-functionality-to-my-wordpress-site)

Comment: @arash Rabiee : Posts can be created by Admin Interface Wordpress, AND can be created by API using ´POST /v2/posts’

Comment: @Steffi so I guess you are using wordpress to add your posts, Can I ask why you don't use meta? For instance each person who liked a post you add wp_post_meta($post_id,$meta,$user_id); and meta could be something like $meta = "liked_by_user_id", then you can easily users which liked each post. I recommend to add another wp_user_meta to keep track of posts which liked by user.

Comment: I think I can’t do that because user can like more than one time the same post. How do you handle that? You update the field by increment ? Yeah, It’s maybe a solution.